# How best to replay all events from genesis using web3

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Using web3 I'm trying to replay all events that have ever happened in order.
Reading the docs, a good way to do this seems to be:

```
  web3.eth.subscribe('logs', { fromBlock: 0}, function() {})
  .on("data", console.log)
  .on("error",console.log)
```

However, even though it says `fromBlock` is supported, it only start playing from the current block the blockchain has just synced.

So how would I replay events from the start? I'm pretty sure I shouldn't have to use 'tracing' since this would actually redo all actual calculations on the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a local node ? Because if you use a service it will be limited to 2M5 queries.

Maybe try {fromBlock : 1} ?

Comment: Yeah I’m using a local node

Comment: with infura node it's working from me, but I filter event for my smart contract only `MyContract.getPastEvents("allEvents", { fromBlock: 100000 }, function (error, events) { })`